# How to get current date to where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(IBML,
              'SELECT PLNITM as Sku_Number,
                      PLNSTR as Store,
                      PLNCDT Start_Date,
                      PLNEVT End_Date,
                      PLNAMT Initial_Price
               FROM PRCPLN
               WHERE PLNAMT > ''99999''
                     and PLNCDT = ?????'
             )
```

How to get the current date, date format is YYDDMM

Comment: What are you looking for? Which DBMS is involved  (you tagged mysql and sql server) - please read the at https://stackoverflow.com/tour and then formulate an actual question that you would like help with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PLNCDT = date_format(now() ,"%y%d%m")` will return current date in `20211802` format in MySql.

In SQL Server it will be

```
PLNCDT =  SELECT format(getdate(), 'yyddMM')
```

Comment: I have changed the format. It will be %y to get two digits year. %Y is for four digit year.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return value as 211802.

`SELECT FORMAT (GETUTCDATE(),'yyddMM')`